# How do I turn off ONLY sounds for notifications?

Tags: iphone, audio, notifications, haptic-feedback

I want to set up my phone so that I have a ringtone and get notifications without sound (haptic only). I have tried 1000 different combinations and didn't manage to do it as I want but I noticed something strange:

Let's take instagram for example - when I go to Settings>Sounds and Haptics and turn off Play Haptics in Ring mode it turns off vibrations as suggested and there is sound alerts when receiving notifications. But when I go to Settings>Notifications>Instragram and and turn off Sounds it turns off BOTH sounds and haptics. Now is that normal or is that a bug.

I just want to have a ringtone for all incoming calls and put notifications on vibration.

**new user using iphone12**

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but check out "Focus". You can customize: silence apps (no vibrate) and allow calls etc.

Answer (score 2):

#### Get a “silent” notification tone

The easiest way to accomplish what you’re looking for is to use a silent notification tone/alert for your notifications.  You can record one with QuickTime or download one off the Internet.  A quick search yielded these [royalty free sound files of silence](https://www.pond5.com/sound-effects/tag/silence/?utm_source=rakuten&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=3624890&ranMID=46113&ranEAID=msYS1Nvjv4c&ranSiteID=msYS1Nvjv4c-WYCBKh2ImVRt2Q2dctUqWQ)

Just use Apple Music (iTunes if on Windows) to sync them to your phone and assign the new file for your notifications.

This also works for macOS.  You can add in the silent notification tone to System Prefences → Sound by copying your AIFF file to `~/Library/Sounds`.  I suggest making it a simple name like "Silence.AIFF" for ease of finding it in the sounds list.

The downside to this is that if you want to re-enable tones for all the alert types, you’ll have to do each one manually.