# How to make timer only vibrate?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I make the built-in timer vibrate but not play any noise when the time is up?

Answer (score 1):

Other than enabling silent mode, the only other way is to assign the [notification a silent alert](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/454038/119271) while keeping haptics enabled.